# How can I get android device "Last activity seen on" & "Registered Date"

Tags: android, activation

On **"Google Dashboard"--> Android --> Devices** I see details for all my past & current devices. The details are:
**IMEI**, **Model Name**, **Manufacturer**, **Carrier**, Last activity seen on and Registered Date.

I would like to know How can I get the last two "dates" programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an int that would use the Calender to get the date. All the information you need to know about this method can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Hi @Ethan, I am not asking how to handle dates. I am asking how can I get the “Last activity seen on” & “Registered Date” dates of my device, as they appear in Google Dashboard.

Comment: My best guess is to create a service that runs onCreate. All it should do is open the webpage, and get the html tag that surrounds those last two dates. Its a long shot, but its my best guess.